# Is iPhone/iPad Safari fully HTML5 compliant?

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, html

This web app http://www.wunderlist.com/ works in HTML5 browsers like Google Chrome or Firefox.

But on iPad the button click doesn't trigger so Is iPhone/iPad Safari fully HTML5 compliant?

Comment: No browser is currently HTML5 compliant.

Comment: If you're looking for specific things that are supported, try http://caniuse.com/ - it's a pretty decent reference and the guy keeps it pretty up to date.

Answer (score 3):

HTML5 itself isn't yet complete, so there is no notion of a fully HTML5-compliant browser.

By the way, you realize there's a native universal iOS app for Wunderlist so you don't have to use the web app on iOS devices, right?

Answer (score 0):

It supports a lot of the HTML5 features, but no browser is completely compliant, because, as BoltClock mentioned, HTML5 hasn't been finalized.

I believe the reason the creators haven't looked into that bug is because there is a great native app for the iPad.

According to Stephen's link, iOS 4.3 has only about 65% of the features that they check for. For example, you can't use `position:fixed` in Safari for iOS.